# Efficient Way to perform batch download from Google Doc using Google Document List API

Tags: android, google-docs, google-docs-api

Currently, I have a few hundred image files, hosted in Google Drive.

I wish to have a way for users to download all images in an efficient way. Here is what I did.

Note, I am using a HttpClient + XML parsing instead of using Google Document List API SDK, as the SDK is not supported in Android. I do not use Google Drive SDK, as its feature is very limited compared to Google Document List API.

---

**Request Google Doc to create archive file out from given image files.**

I send a POST request to `https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/archive?v=3`, by specificity which image files I want them to be in archive. Once my POST request completed, server will return me `<docs:archiveStatus>archiving</docs:archiveStatus>`. The server needs time to perform archiving.

**Keep quering Google Doc till I get 'finished' status**

***This is the part where inefficiency is there.*** Currently, I have no way to know when will the archiving process done, but keep query on the status by using link from previous respond `<link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/archive/nTSZLt...32zRB3U?v=3`.

I need to keep repeating same query again and again, till I get `<docs:archiveStatus>finished</docs:archiveStatus>`.

Only with that, I can obtain the archive download link through `<content type='application/zip' src='https://doc-00-90-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/secure/he...30&gd=true' />`

---

Is there any efficient way I can use, to avoid multiple queries on the same URL again and again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only alternative I can think of would be monitoring the email address specified in the `<docs:archiveNotify>` element of the archive creation request, but I'm not sure whether that is more efficient.